# SQL Subtract Hours

Tags: sql, datetime

In SQL I have one column A (float) which contains 2173.03 value. You can read this as 2173 Hours and 3 minutes.

I have another column-(B) in float which contains 2171.33 value. Same way you can read this as 2171 Hours and 33 Minutes.

In SQL I want to subtract Column B From A.

So what I need is to convert Column A's 2173 in Minutes and then want to add 3 minutes to the result.

```
Column A: 2173 * 60 + 03 = 1,30,383 Minutes
Column B: 2171 * 60 + 33 = 1,30,293 Minutes

Column A-B = 90 Minutes
```

I want the result as 1.30. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use round function?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Use proper interval data type.

Comment: **1)** One should not use `FLOAT` in databases, if not really necessary, because that's an approximate datatype. Use a precise type instead (`DECIMAL` in most DBMS). **2)** 2173.03 = 2173 hours and 3 minutes? What is 2173.78 then? This is a *very* bad way to store hours and minutes. I would have expected 2173.03 to mean 2173.03 hours, i.e. 2173 hours and 1.8 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using such an arcane format?  Why not just decimal minutes, where the decimals mean what decimals mean?

You can convert to decimal minutes by doing:

```
select (floor(cola) - (cola - floor(cola)) * 100.0 / 60)
```

Then do the subtraction:

```
select ( (floor(cola) - (cola - floor(cola)) * 100.0 / 60) -
         (floor(colb) - (colb - floor(colb)) * 100.0 / 60)
       )
```

And then to convert back, I would use a subquery:

```
select (floor(decimal_minutes) + 
        (decimal_minutes - floor(decimal_minutes) * 60.0 / 100)
       )
from (select ( (floor(cola) - (cola - floor(cola)) * 100.0 / 60) -
               (floor(colb) - (colb - floor(colb)) * 100.0 / 60)
             ) as decimal_minutes
     ) x
```

However, I would strongly advise you to change the meaning of the column to either decimal minutes or just seconds.

Comment: okay...you're answering too fast on every question out there right now!!